# Reliable method to exit a Tkinter GUI on Mac without using sys.exit()

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

My main goal is to **package a GUI within a PyPi distribution that allows the user to import, open, and cleanly exit the GUI without using sys.exit().**

Here's a barebones example:

`gui.py`:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button
class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        Button(text='QUIT',command=lambda:[self.destroy(),self.quit()]).grid(row=0,column=0)

def run():
    root = GUI()
    root.mainloop()
```

Now, if I'm working with this as a package, I would call:

```py
>>> import gui
>>> gui.run()
```

When I click the 'QUIT' button, python hangs, the window stays open, and I must force quit. While adding sys.exit() to the 'QUIT' command does work, it kills the Python session, which I **do not want to do**, since there are other features of my package I want the user to be able to access after closing the GUI. This also doesn't work when directly running the code using `if __name__ == "__main__"`.

This code works just fine on Windows - it creates a python.exe instance, and cleanly quits with no issues when pressing 'QUIT'. Any ideas on how to do the same with Mac?

Comment: `self.destroy()` should be all you need to do. That will destroy the root window and cause `mainloop()` to exit. Have you trid `command=self.destroy` without also trying to call `self.quit()`? Though, your code works fine for me on my Mac.

Comment: Yes, using only self.destroy does not close the window or the application.

Comment: Are you using some sort of tool to convert the python code to an app? When I literally create a file named gui.py like in your question, and then use that module in an interactive prompt like in the question, it all behaves like I expect.

Comment: So you use the exact approach as above? I am doing the same and it is not working. Maybe this is a bad install? What shell are you using - I am using Terminal.

Comment: Yes, I use the exact approach as described in your question. I created a file named "gui.py" with a copy/paste of the code. I then ran an interactive python shell and typed in `import gui` followed by `gui.run()`. Then I clicked the quit button. After that, I could type other commands into the prompt.

Comment: For whatever reason, I cannot do that. Maybe a reinstall of python is in order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217026/discussion-between-nic-thibodeaux-and-bryan-oakley).

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```py
root.destroy()
```

And maybe this will work

Edit : replace root by the name of your window, like if you say:

```py
from tkinter import *
mywindow = Tk()
mywindow.mainloop()
```

Then do :

```py
mywindow.destroy()
```

Exemple with your code :

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button
class GUI(Tk):
    def quit():
        self.destroy()
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        Button(text='QUIT',command=quit).grid(row=0,column=0)

def run():
    root = GUI()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I want to keep my GUI within a class. I do use the destroy() command in the lambda, but I tried moving it into run() after mainloop() and it still does not work.

Can you provide an example of what you mean using my code structure?

Comment: Yeah, let me a second ! ^^

Comment: Ok check the edit I made in my answer and tell me if this is what you want !

Comment: The problem is that this example does the same as sys.exit() - it exits the python shell.

Comment: Oh ok yeah I see now, I understand... Well I'll search and I tell you if I find ! ^^

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277257/how-to-close-a-tkinter-window-without-terminating-the-program
The first answer is not stupid at all... This could work